# Particle System only playing on start and end of GetButton()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, particle-system

I'm making an FPS and below is my GunScript:

```
{
    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;
    public float fireRate = 5f;
    public float impactForce = 30f;

    public Camera playerCam;
    public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
    public GameObject impactEffect;

    private float nextTimeToFire = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTimeToFire)
        {
            nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        muzzleFlash.Play();

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(playerCam.transform.position, playerCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

            Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();
            if (target != null)
            {
                target.TakeDamage(damage);
            }

            if (hit.rigidbody != null)
            {
                hit.rigidbody.AddForce(-hit.normal * impactForce);
            }

            Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
        }
    }
}
```

However the particle system only plays when I push down my mouse or lift up on my mouse. It should play continuously when my mouse is pushed down. Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide setting for your particle system, I don't see any problem here. Maybe your visible effect for muzzle flash plays later than another bullet shots, in this case your particle system resets by `Play()` before you can see anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you only play it in the `Shoot()` method, which is called only every time you fire, but I don't know what your particle system looks like. If you want it to play continuously, you should put it outside of the `Shoot()` method in a separate if statement in `Update()` or modify it like so:

```
if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
{
    muzzleFlash.Play();
    if (Time.time >= nextTimeToFire) 
    {
        nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
        Shoot();
    }
}
```